# Merge tables MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

I would like to know how to join different tables in mysql. For example, an article table with various columns, a favorite articles table, a comments table and a favorite comments table. I would like to list both articles and favorite comments on one page. How could I do?
Article table:

```
id   id_user        unique_id
1    1              dhdej4      
2    1              sr4r44
```

Article translation table:

```
id   id_article     article     lang
1    1              something   en   
2    2              something   en
```

Favorite article table:

```
id   id_article_favorite   id_user_favorite
1    1                     1   
2    2                     1
```

Hashtag table:

```
id        hashtag
1         something  
2         something
```

Favorite hashtag table:

```
id   id_hashtag_favorite    id_user_favorite
1    1                      2   
2    2                      2
```

I would like to get all these tables to merge, I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM article a
  JOIN article_translation t
    ON a.id = t.id_article 
  JOIN favorite_article fa
    ON fa.id_article_favorite = t.id_article 
  JOIN hashtag h
  JOIN favorite_hashtag fh
    ON fh.id_favorite_hashtag = h.id 
 WHERE fa.id_user_favorite = 1
   AND t.lang = 'en'
   AND fh.id_user_favorite = 1
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: You should have an `ON` clause for `comment`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select * 
from article a
inner join article_translation at on at.id_article          = a.id
inner join favorite_article fa    on fa.id_article_favorite = a.id
inner join comment c              on c.id_article_comment   = a.id
inner join favorite_comment fc    on fc.id_comment_favorite = a.id 
where fa.id_user_favorite = 1 and at.lang = 'en'
```

I attempted to fix the join conditions between the tables. Presumably, all tables related to `article` through foreign key constraints. You might want to review that in light of your actual schema.

I also added table aliases, which make the query easier to write and read.

I would recommend enumerating the columns you want in the `select` lause rather than using `select *`; this makes the intent of the query clearer, and gives you a chance to alias columns whose name is not unique.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I corrected an error in my tables (I tried to simplify for this I was wrong). Pretend that the comments table is actually the hashtag table (the hashtag and articles table have nothing in common). sorry again

Comment: @Gae: your question is rather unclear about how tables relate to each other. You will probably need to build on this answer to generate the proper query for your use case.